# Which one does this "it" mean?

Tags: grammar, sentence-meaning, pronouns

I'm trying to understand this sentence about which subject the "it" represents:

> If the current window was closed by an autocommand while processing a
> location list command, it will be aborted.

So it's the current window, or the autocommand, will get aborted?

Comment: Could you clarify what you’re asking for? I don’t really understand.

Comment: @Buzzyy: What will be aborted?

Answer (score 2):

The processing of the location list command will be aborted.

The window will have been ‘aborted’ already due to the auto command closing it, meaning that the only thing left is the processing. I’m guessing this i only if the window was doing this process in the first place.